# R's approxfun in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

What is the equivalent for R's `approxfun` in Matlab?

I used `interp3()` to calculate the interpolation points, now I need to create an inverse function to perform this interpolation. Any ideas?

Comment: A quick search (with my favorite `library(sos); findFn("3d interpolation")`) finds nothing.  You may be stuck writing it yourself ... linear interpolation should be fairly easy. Splines could be harder. The `mgcv` package can do 3d smoothing splines, but I don't know about interpolation splines. Searching "3d interpolation" on http://rseek.org found some stuff on the mailing lists but don't know if any of it is really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need the inverse of a function you should simply reverse the order of the x and y values. So if interp3( x, y)  gets you a satisfactory function, then interp3( y, x) should produce the inverse, subject of course to the possibility you may need to do it piecewise if it is not monotonic.